# Creating a sequence of dates for each group in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, seq

I have a dataset that consists of multiple stores/retailers:

```
RETAILER    VOLUME  DISP    PRICE
store1      12      15      10
store1      10      8       17
store1      12      13      12
...
store2      22      22      30
store2      17      14      22
store2      23      18      18
...
store3      11      13      10
store3      12      13      13
store3      14      12      11
```

Unfortunately this data set does not contain dates so I need to generate date sequences for each store within this table. Frequency isn't really that important - days or months will be ok.

To make it easier let's assume that it starts on 2000-01-01 and number of dates for each RETAILER depends on number of observations for this RETAILER.

I'm able to handle this in R:

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(RETAILER) %>% 
  group_by(RETAILER) %>%  
  mutate(dates = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = n()))
```

However, I'm unable to replicate this in Python. I've been trying with pd.date_range(), but can't find the solution.

Can anyone please suggest some way to perform this task in Python?

The desired output:

```
RETAILER    VOLUME  DISP    PRICE   DATE
store1      12      15      10      2000-01-01
store1      10      8       17      2000-02-01
store1      12      13      12      2000-03-01
...
store2      22      22      30      2000-01-01
store2      17      14      22      2000-02-01
store2      23      18      18      2000-03-01
...
store3      11      13      10      2000-01-01
store3      12      13      13      2000-02-01
store3      14      12      11      2000-03-01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us `group` the dataframe on `RETAILER` and use `cumcount` to create sequential counter per `RETAILER` then `map` this counter to `MonthBegin` offset and add a `Timestamp('2000-01-01')`:

```
c = df.groupby('RETAILER').cumcount()
df['DATE'] = pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01') + c.map(pd.offsets.MonthBegin)
```

---

```
  RETAILER  VOLUME  DISP  PRICE       DATE
0   store1      12    15     10 2000-01-01
1   store1      10     8     17 2000-02-01
2   store1      12    13     12 2000-03-01
3   store2      22    22     30 2000-01-01
4   store2      17    14     22 2000-02-01
5   store2      23    18     18 2000-03-01
6   store3      11    13     10 2000-01-01
7   store3      12    13     13 2000-02-01
8   store3      14    12     11 2000-03-01
```

Comment: Thank you! That indeed does the trick. Seems that switching from R to Python isn't going to be as easy as i thought. :)

Comment: @Freejack It will be much easier once you get acquainted with python world and its goin to be much more fun ;)